# android.view.InflateException: Can't morph from @string/path_password_eye_mask_strike_through to @string/path_password_eye_mask_visible

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication, render, android-textinputlayout

So when I build the project I receive no errors. The app crashes in the emulator and says Unfortunately the project has stopped.
In the preview window I see several errors and have researched them to no avail the main one being that it failed to parse a file because it **cant morph from @string/path password_eye_mask_strike_through can morph from to @string/path_password_eye_mask_visible**

and that theres a render problem because  **tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:padding='20dp'
    tools:context="activities.LoginActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/new_logo" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_name"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorText"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutEmail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextEmail"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_email"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorText"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutPassword"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextPassword"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorText"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutConfirmPassword"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/textInputEditConfirmPassword"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_confirm_password"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorText"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/appCompatButtonRegister"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:background="@color/colorTextHint"
            android:text="@string/text_register"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/appCompatTextViewLoginLink"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text_member"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText" />






    </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

error Log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: edu.spelman.spelfitscmail.spelfit, PID: 4183
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.spelman.spelfitscmail.spelfit/edu.spelman.spelfitscmail.spelfit.activities.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at edu.spelman.spelfitscmail.spelfit.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at edu.spelman.spelfitscmail.spelfit.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:39) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at edu.spelman.spelfitscmail.spelfit.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:39) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "edu.spelman.spelfitscmail.spelfit:drawable/new_logo" (7f07006b) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f07006b a=-1 r=0x7f07006b}
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2602)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:72)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at edu.spelman.spelfitscmail.spelfit.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:39) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4183 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

You can see the error in xml preview too.

Comment: Please add the error log

Comment: You should not be using the `AppCompatImageView` directly. You should use the regular `ImageView` in your XML, and appcompat will take care of the rest. I quote from the docs; AppCompatImageView will automatically be used when you use ImageView in your layouts and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.

Comment: facing same issue "android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout' is causing the problem, removing it removes error

Comment: any solution for this yet?